# Insert into SQL Server table only if some columns are not duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [name] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

It has data like:

```
ID  name   address  value    date
-----------------------------------------------------
1   a      1         10      2020-08-27 06:06:29.833
2   b      2         30      2020-08-28 06:06:29.833
3   c      3         5       2020-08-27 06:06:29.833
4   d      4         30      2020-08-28 06:06:29.833
```

I am doing a bulk insert to this table. While inserting I do not want to insert if the data is duplicated for (name, address, value). I want to silently insert the data.

So if input data to be inserted is:

```
ID  name   address  value    date
-----------------------------------------------------
5   e      5         10      2020-08-27 06:06:29.833
6   b      2         30      2020-08-29 06:06:29.833
7   c      3         5       2020-08-30 06:06:29.833
8   f      4         30      2020-08-28 06:06:29.833
```

Then only rows with ID's 5 and 8 to be inserted and the rows with id's 6 and 7 be considered duplicate and should not be inserted as new and in the final table (name, address,value) is always unique.

My Bad. Input data is not coming from a table.
It is a list in python.

list = [['e', 5, 10], ['b', 2,30], ['c', 3, 5], ['f', 4,30]]

And currently my query is:

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO Person(ID,name,address,value,date) VALUES ( newID(),%s, %s, %s,getDate());"
cursor.executemany(insert_query, list)
```

I want to have something like:

```
insert_query = "INSERT INTO Person(ID,name,address,value,date) VALUES ( newID(),%s, %s, %s,getDate()) on duplicate(name,address,value) ignore that insert;"
cursor.executemany(insert_query, list)
```

Comment: Please show us your `insert` code.

Comment: Have you tried something? Have checked any other SO questions, searched for answers? This is a very common question, easily solved with a self-join or an EXISTS clause. I noticed at least one similar question this week

Comment: " in the final table (name, address,value) is always unique." Well the first thing I would do is create a unique constraint (or index) on these columns, even before I go to deal with the inserts.

Comment: But this will raise error. I want a silent insert of other new rows where data is not duplicated

Answer (score 3):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
insert into person (name, address, value, date)
select x.*
from (values (@name, @address, @value, @date)) as x(name, address, value, date)
where not exists (
    select 1
    from person p1
    where p1.name = p.name and p1.address = p.address and p1.value = p.value
)
```